# Starting sentence with "at"?

Tags: prepositions, inversion, commas

If I start a sentence with the prepostion "at", Should I use a comma? For example:

> At the university, if you have PhD degree, you are entitled to teach
>   there. At home university, I didn't register in doctoral program.

Or, should I put it at the end of the sentence?

Answer (score 3):

Prepositional phrases at the beginning of sentences are common and grammatically correct. So you may start your sentence with 'at'.

When you start a sentence with a prepositional phrase, it's usually a good idea to put a comma after it. In general, the longer the prepositional phrase, the more you need the comma.